# Pointing a range at the end of a table cell

Tags: perl, ms-word, win32ole, word-table

In a Perl CGI, using Win32::OLE, I need to insert several text lines in a table cell, but one by one.

The different objects I use are :

- *$go_document*, the Word document
- *$lo_table*, the Word table
- *$li_row* and *$li_col*, the cell coordinates in the table
- *@ly_lines*, the text array

Here's my code, which works properly:

```
for (my $ii = 0; $ii <= $#ly_lines; $i++)
{
    my $lo_range = $lo_table->Cell($li_row, $li_col)->Range;
    $lo_range->InsertAfter($ly_lines[$ii]);

    $lo_range = $lo_table->Cell($li_row, $li_col)->Range;
    $lo_range->InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

My problem happens when I try to apply a style to each one of the text lines.

Since I don't want to set the style of the entire cell but of the line I'm about to insert, I tried this (the styles being stored in the *@ly_styles* array):

```
for (my $ii = 0; $ii <= $#ly_lines; $i++)
{
    my $lo_range = $lo_table->Cell($li_row, $li_col)->Range;
    $lo_range->Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);

    $go_document->Styles->Add($ly_styles[$ii]);
    $lo_range->{'Style'} = $ly_styles;
    $lo_range->InsertAfter($ly_lines[$ii]);

    $lo_range = $lo_table->Cell($li_row, $li_col)->Range;
    $lo_range->Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);

    $lo_range->InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

With this loop, the text lines read **in a reversed order and in the cell next to the one I want**!

It seems that the *Collapse(wdCollapseEnd)* command doesn't set the range to the end of the aimed cell, but to the beginning of the next one.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Immediately after `wdCollapseEnd` try moving the range backwards by a character:

```
$lo_range->MoveEnd(wdCharacter, -1)
```

The "why" is a bit arcane and I'm not sure if what I imagine is the reason is is correct... What I believe is the reason is that collapsing the Range puts the focus at the beginning of the next cell. Think of it as if the entire cell were selected and pressing right-arrow moved to the next cell instead of at the end of the text in the selected cell. So it's necessary to move back one character (like pressing left-arrow) to get to the end of the original cell.

`Range` has `MoveEnd` and `MoveStart`. Using a positive number with `MoveStart` or a negative number with `MoveEnd` will effectively move the entire `Range` without including additional content. A negative value with `MoveStart` or a positive value with `MoveEnd` will extand the `Range` to include new content. Again, think of it like using the arrow keys, but this time with `Shift` held down to extend the selection. There are various parameters (`WdUnits` Enumeration) that can be used with these methods that work with objects such as cells, paragraphs, etc. The list can be found in the Word Language Reference.